# From a java.net.URL containing a file (file:///path/to/file) to a java.nio.FileChannel

Tags: java, real-time, nio, bytebuffer

Is it possible? Basically I have a local binary file represented by:

`file:///path/to/myfile.dat`

I want to read this file using `ByteBuffer`s, in other words, I believe I need a `FileChannel` from the given URL to do that.

Any hope?

Comment: @JohnD It is a URL. It has a scheme and a scheme-dependent part.

Comment: @JohnD I tried with my browser and I can open a local file. The correct URL has 3 '/' instead of 2 (my bad) => `file:///path/to/mylocalfile.dat` (Obs: I fixed my original URL that had incorrectly two '/' instead of 3)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just get the path out of the URL and open it with `FileChannel.open()`.

Comment: Calling URL.getPath() or URL.getfile() will not return a valid filename.  It will return the path portion of the URL, with all percent escapes.  A URL should be converted to a Path with `Paths.get(url.toURI())`.